# Detaching and attaching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$('th').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    var column = $th.index();
    var $table = $th.closest('table');
    var rows = $table.find('tbody > tr').get();
    rows.sort(function(rowA,rowB) {
        var keyA = $(rowA).children('td').eq(column).text().toUpperCase();
        var keyB = $(rowB).children('td').eq(column).text().toUpperCase();
        if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
        if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    $.each(rows, function(index,row) {
      $table.children('tbody').append(row);
    });
});
```

I think it would execute faster if I detached the tbody before sorting it and then attached it back.

Q: How do I use detach and attach to correctly move tbody in and out of the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to know where the table is coming from... i.e. if the table were inside a wrapper DIV with ID="tablewrapper", you could change your `var $table` line to:

```
var $table = $th.closest('table').detach();
```

and at the end of your function add:

```
$table.appendTo('#tablewrapper');
```

I'm not convinced detaching it will speed things up, and am interested in the results you get.

Comment: Could I use $table.detach('tbody')?

Comment: I was curious about the speed increase so I made a jsperf http://jsperf.com/to-detach-or-not-to-detach  first I created a very small table and the increase was small in chrome, so I made it huge, still a small performance increase.  And yes you can detach the tbody.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn you can try... maybe var $tbody = $table.find('tbody').detach(); ?

Comment: Update, the performance is way better in IE, which I guess makes sense since IE is slow to update the dom.